# ¿Cómo puedo poner en mayúsculas la primera letra de cada palabra en una frase con Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Si yo inserto un nombre en la caja de texto, por ejemplo LuCíA péRez, ¿que código tengo que insertar en el espacio en blanco en el código JS para que las palabras LuCíA péRez, que pueden ser otras, tengan como resultado Lucía Pérez? Gracias de antemano

```js
function convertir() {
 var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value
 
 
 var Nombrefinalconvertido 
 document.getElementById("textoamostrar").innerHTML = Nombrefinalconvertido
}
```

```html
<input id="nombre" placeholder="Escribe tu nombre..."> <button onclick="convertir()">Convertir a nombre propio</button>
<p id="textoamostrar"></p>
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Podrías hacerlo con una mezcla de [`toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/toUpperCase) y [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/toLowerCase) y como dice tu *nick*: ***programando siempre***. Saludos

Comment: He intentado poner un nombre para que, en el caso de que la persona que lo escriba en mayusculas o en minusculas, se corrija automaticamente ¿como lo hago? ¿A qué te reiferes con mi nick?

Comment: @Programandosiempre a lo que Mauricio se refiere en una primer instancia es que te valgas de los 2 métodos mencionados para lograrlo, segundo que trates de tu hacer algo que programes un intento y ya cuando algo falle entonces lo agregues a tu pregunta

Comment: Hola, BetaM, sin ánimo de ofender, siempre estoy programando, lo cuál no implica que no haga ese intento, por lo que no es más que un nick, y que también hago otras cosas. Entonces, es mejor ahorrarse esos comentarios. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Creo que puedes hacer esto, primero convertir toda la cadena a minúsculas y usar split para tratar cada palabra ingresada por separado y manejar la cadena como un arreglo, luego en un for conviertes a mayúscula el primer carácter de la palabra y el resto a minúsculas. Ojala te sirva.

```js
function convertir() {

var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value 

var cadena = nombre.toLowerCase().split(' ');

for (var i = 0; i < cadena.length; i++) {
 cadena[i] = cadena[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + cadena[i].substring(1);
}
nombre = cadena.join(' ');

document.getElementById("textoamostrar").innerHTML = nombre
}
```

```html
<input id="nombre" placeholder="Escribe tu nombre..."> <button onclick="convertir()">Convertir a nombre propio</button>
<p id="textoamostrar"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Este código te lo pasa todo a minúsculas, en realidad no lo capitaliza por lo que se encarga el CSS (desde JS). Quizás pueda resolver tu problema

```
<script>
    nombre=document.querySelector("#nombre");
    nombre.textContent=nombre.textContent.toLowerCase();
    nombre.style.textTransform="capitalize";
</script>
```

Asi que para usarlo para mostrarlo al usuario es valido.
Espero que te sirva mi sugerencia

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes una forma usando expresiones regulares:

```js
function convertir() {
    // Recibes el texto input del html y conviertes todos los caracteres a minúscula
    let nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value.toLowerCase();
 
    // Esta expresion regular busca un conjunto de caracteres que no sean espacios
    //Cada grupo encontrado lo remplaza por si mismo con la primera letra mayuscula
    nombre = nombre.replace(/([^\s]+)/gm, function (textoEncontrado) {
            return textoEncontrado.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + textoEncontrado.substring(1);
    });
 
    // Finalmente asignas el output al elemento hmtl
    document.getElementById("textoamostrar").innerHTML = nombre;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="nombre" placeholder="Escribe tu nombre..."> 
    <button onclick="convertir()">Convertir a nombre propio</button>
    <p id="textoamostrar"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor explica tu código